# In express-cors, how do I end the middlewhere chain when a domain does not match?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I did the example here and see that it does work by including the Access Origin Allow headers when the request Origin matches one of the allowedOrigins below.

https://github.com/ybogdanov/express-cors

```
var cors = require('express-cors')

app.use(cors({
    allowedOrigins: [
        'github.com', 'google.com'
    ]
}))

curl -v -H "Origin: https://github.com" http://localhost:3000/
```

However, it does not stop the request in express js.  Kind of defeats the purpose.   In other words, my the next middle ware runs even though the domain did not match.  So the browser knows it was not allowed (I see it in the console) but the server will continue to execute the request.  I need `express-cors` to end the request.

Do I need to do this manually (like the `match` in the unit test): https://github.com/ybogdanov/express-cors/blob/master/test.js .. This seems odd.

Why would the middlewhere continue if it did not match?

> index.js

```
// express middleware
return function(req, res, next){
var origin = req.get('Origin'), i, matched = false

// match against all prepared regexp origins
for (i = 0; i < allowedOrigins.length; i++) {
  if (allowedOrigins[i].test(origin)) {
    matched = true
    break
  }
}

if (!matched) return next()
//...
```

Comment: https://github.com/ybogdanov/express-cors/issues/5

Comment: I think you could easily change line 75 to if (!matched) return;  That should do what you are looking to do.  I am not sure why they would continue to call next() in that situation.

Comment: This is a very popular project, it looks like a security problem to me.

Comment: You could always make the change and submit a pull request.  If anything, it should be an option.